# process of late events in SA

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

I was doing a test, when I generated data that was 30 days old.
When sent to SA job all that input was dropped, but per settings in **event ordering** blade I was expecting that all will be passed thru.

Part of job query contains:

```
---------------all incoming events storage query
SELECT stream.*
INTO [iot-predict-SA2-ColdStorage]
FROM [iot-predict-SA2-input] stream TIMESTAMP BY stream.UtcTime
```

so my expectation is to have everything that was pushed to SA job in blob storage.

When I sent events that were only 5 hours old  - then the input was marked as late (expected) and processed.
Per SS first marked area is showing outdated events input, but no output (red), the second part shows late processed events.

### full query

```
    WITH AlertsBasedOnMin
    AS (
        SELECT stream.SensorGuid
            ,stream.Value
            ,stream.SensorName
            ,ref.AggregationTypeFlag
            ,ref.MinThreshold AS threshold
            ,ref.Count
            ,CASE 
                WHEN (ref.MinThreshold > stream.Value)
                    THEN 1
                ELSE 0
                END AS isAlert
        FROM [iot-predict-SA2-input] stream TIMESTAMP BY stream.UtcTime
        JOIN [iot-predict-SA2-referenceBlob] ref ON ref.SensorGuid = stream.SensorGuid
        WHERE ref.AggregationTypeFlag = 8
        )
        ,AlertsBasedOnMax
    AS (
        SELECT stream.SensorGuid
            ,stream.Value
            ,stream.SensorName
            ,ref.AggregationTypeFlag
            ,ref.MaxThreshold AS threshold
            ,ref.Count
            ,CASE 
                WHEN (ref.MaxThreshold < stream.Value)
                    THEN 1
                ELSE 0
                END AS isAlert
        FROM [iot-predict-SA2-input] stream TIMESTAMP BY stream.UtcTime
        JOIN [iot-predict-SA2-referenceBlob] ref ON ref.SensorGuid = stream.SensorGuid
        WHERE ref.AggregationTypeFlag = 16
        )
        ,alertMinMaxUnion
    AS (
        SELECT *
        FROM AlertsBasedOnMin

        UNION ALL

        SELECT *
        FROM AlertsBasedOnMax
        )
        ,alertMimMaxComputed
    AS (
        SELECT SUM(alertMinMaxUnion.isAlert) AS EventCount
            ,alertMinMaxUnion.SensorGuid AS SensorGuid
            ,alertMinMaxUnion.SensorName
        FROM alertMinMaxUnion
        GROUP BY HoppingWindow(Duration(minute, 1), Hop(second, 30))
            ,alertMinMaxUnion.SensorGuid
            ,alertMinMaxUnion.Count
            ,alertMinMaxUnion.AggregationTypeFlag
            ,alertMinMaxUnion.SensorName
        HAVING SUM(alertMinMaxUnion.isAlert) > alertMinMaxUnion.Count
        )
        ,alertsMimMaxComputedMergedWithReference
    AS (
        SELECT System.TIMESTAMP [TimeStampUtc]
            ,computed.EventCount
            ,0 AS SumValue
            ,0 AS AvgValue
            ,0 AS StdDevValue
            ,computed.SensorGuid
            ,computed.SensorName
            ,ref.MinThreshold
            ,ref.MaxThreshold
            ,ref.TimeFrameInSeconds
            ,ref.Count
            ,ref.GatewayGuid
            ,ref.SensorType
            ,ref.AggregationType
            ,ref.AggregationTypeFlag
            ,ref.EmailList
            ,ref.PhoneNumberList
        FROM alertMimMaxComputed computed
        JOIN [iot-predict-SA2-referenceBlob] ref ON ref.SensorGuid = computed.SensorGuid
        )
        ,alertsAggregatedByFunction
    AS (
        SELECT Count(1) AS eventCount
            ,stream.SensorGuid AS SensorGuid
            ,stream.SensorName
            ,ref.[Count] AS TriggerThreshold
            ,SUM(stream.Value) AS SumValue
            ,AVG(stream.Value) AS AvgValue
            ,STDEV(stream.Value) AS StdDevValue
            ,ref.AggregationTypeFlag AS flag
        FROM [iot-predict-SA2-input] stream TIMESTAMP BY stream.UtcTime
        JOIN [iot-predict-SA2-referenceBlob] ref ON ref.SensorGuid = stream.SensorGuid
        GROUP BY HoppingWindow(Duration(minute, 1), Hop(second, 30))
            ,ref.AggregationTypeFlag
            ,ref.[Count]
            ,ref.MaxThreshold
            ,ref.MinThreshold
            ,stream.SensorGuid
            ,stream.SensorName
        HAVING
            --as this is alert then this factor will be relevant to all of the aggregated queries
            Count(1) >= ref.[Count]
            AND (
                --average
                (
                    ref.AggregationTypeFlag = 1
                    AND (
                        AVG(stream.Value) >= ref.MaxThreshold
                        OR AVG(stream.Value) <= ref.MinThreshold
                        )
                    )
                --sum
                OR (
                    ref.AggregationTypeFlag = 2
                    AND (
                        SUM(stream.Value) >= ref.MaxThreshold
                        OR Sum(stream.Value) <= ref.MinThreshold
                        )
                    )
                --stdev 
                OR (
                    ref.AggregationTypeFlag = 4
                    AND (
                        STDEV(stream.Value) >= ref.MaxThreshold
                        OR STDEV(stream.Value) <= ref.MinThreshold
                        )
                    )
                )
        )
        ,alertsAggregatedByFunctionMergedWithReference
    AS (
        SELECT System.TIMESTAMP [TimeStampUtc]
            ,0 AS EventCount
            ,computed.SumValue
            ,computed.AvgValue
            ,computed.StdDevValue
            ,computed.SensorGuid
            ,computed.SensorName
            ,ref.MinThreshold
            ,ref.MaxThreshold
            ,ref.TimeFrameInSeconds
            ,ref.Count
            ,ref.GatewayGuid
            ,ref.SensorType
            ,ref.AggregationType
            ,ref.AggregationTypeFlag
            ,ref.EmailList
            ,ref.PhoneNumberList
        FROM alertsAggregatedByFunction computed
        JOIN [iot-predict-SA2-referenceBlob] ref ON ref.SensorGuid = computed.SensorGuid
        )
        ,allAlertsUnioned
    AS (
        SELECT *
        FROM alertsAggregatedByFunctionMergedWithReference

        UNION ALL

        SELECT *
        FROM alertsMimMaxComputedMergedWithReference
        )


    ---------------alerts storage query 
    SELECT *
    INTO [iot-predict-SA2-Alerts-ColdStorage]
    FROM allAlertsUnioned

    ---------------alerts to alert events query
    SELECT *
    INTO [iot-predict-SA2-Alerts-EventStream]
    FROM allAlertsUnioned


    ---------------alerts to stream query
    SELECT *
    INTO [iot-predict-SA2-TSI-EventStream]
    FROM allAlertsUnioned


    ---------------all incoming events storage query
    SELECT stream.*
    INTO [iot-predict-SA2-ColdStorage]
    FROM [iot-predict-SA2-input] stream TIMESTAMP BY stream.UtcTime


    ---------------all incoming events to time insights query
    SELECT stream.*
    INTO [iot-predict-SA2-TSI-AlertStream]
    FROM [iot-predict-SA2-input] stream TIMESTAMP BY stream.UtcTime
```

[image: Sa output]

Comment: Have you checked "Diagnose and solve problems" section under your stream analytics job about job is not outputting data? Also, here is a blog about troubleshooting stream analytics job, you could refer to [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/streamanalytics/2016/05/13/troubleshooting-azure-stream-analytics-jobs-with-select-into/).

Comment: hi Bruce - in this particular case i have select  stream.* into blob, will add full query in a minute

Comment: @Bruce-MSFT even OP has that select stream.* :) - query added

Comment: Have you checked the metrics for Run-time Errors or Data Conversion Errors? Also, please check the operations log messages for additional details or update your question with operations log for us to locate this issue.

Comment: @Bruce-MSFT will gather that tomorrow as im ooo currently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a chat with guys from MS, it emerged that my test have to had an extra step to perform.

To have late events processed, regardless late event settings, we need to start this job in a way, that late event is considered  as a sent when job was started, so in this particular case, we have to start SA job using custom start date and set it 30 days ago.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using "TIMESTAMP BY", Stream Analytics job event ordering settings are taking effects. Please check your job's "event ordering" settings, specifically below two:

- Events that arrive late -- the late arrival limit between 0 second and 21 days.
- Handling other events -- error handling policy, drop or adjust the application time to system clock time.

I guess that, most likely, your late arrival limit was more than 5 hours, so that those 5-hours old events could be processed.

You may already figure out from above that Stream Analytics job can only process "old" events up to 21 days late. To work around this limitation, you can consider one of below options:

1. Remove TIMESTAMP BY, then all your windowing aggregate will be using enqueue time. This might generate incorrect result according to your query logic.
2. Select "adjust" as the error handling policy. Again, this might generate incorrect result according to your query logic.
3. Shifting the application time (stream.UtcTime) to a more resent time by using DATEADD() function, for example TIMESTAMP BY DATEADD(day, 10, UtcTime). This works well when this is a onetime task, and you know the time range of your events.
4. Use batch job(outside Stream Analytics) to process data that 30 days old.

Comment: hi did all the stuff, still Im expecting adjust behavior not drop